# Error al momento de retornar una funcion php con Twilio

Tags: php, laravel, twilio

estoy tratando de implementar una API para whatsapp con Twilio con php, entonces tengo problemas al momento de estar llamando al método, porque aparece un error "Target does not exist", tengo todos los modos de redireccionamiento dentro del Web.php, también estoy retornando una vista, aunque esto último no estoy muy seguro, le dejo los 3 bloques de código

Esta es por parte de la clase web.php

```
 Route::get('/mensaje', [BlogControllers::class, 'message'])->name('mensaje');
```

Y este es por parte de la vista, este es el botón que acciona el mensaje

```
 <a class="btn rightLst" href="{{mensaje}}" >></a>
```

Y este es el código del controlador

```
 public function message(){
   

    // Use the REST API Client to make requests to the Twilio REST API
    
    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    // Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
    $sid = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $client = new Client($sid, $token);
    
    // Use the client to do fun stuff like send text messages!
    $client->messages->create(
        // the number you'd like to send the message to
        'NumeroTelefono',
        [
            // A Twilio phone number you purchased at twilio.com/console
            'from' => '+1 (415) 523-0000',
            // the body of the text message you'd like to send
            'body' => 'Hola mundo prueba'
        ]
    );
    return view('index');
}
```

También estuve intentando hacer toda la dirección, pero sigue saliendo el mismo error, espero que puedan apoyarme en esa parte

Comment: la clase client a que hacer referencia?

Comment: Hace referencia a la API de Twilio, nos conectamos con el Sid y el token

Answer (score 0):

No se si tengas todavía el mismo problema, pero creo que te falto añadir esta linea para llamar a la libreria de Twilio

```
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
```

(para esto debiste instalar composer require twilio/sdk)

ya que lo llamas en la siguiente linea y es por esto que te aparece que no existe:

```
$client = new Client($sid, $token);
```

como recomendación, te sugiero que cuando hagas una pregunta por este medio no subas tus credenciales que usas en

> $sid
> $token

ya que alguien mas podría hacer uso de ellas.

Saludos!